# Where is scala-swing.jar in Ubuntu 16? It was in Ubuntu 14

Tags: 16.04, apt, java, scala

For the life of me, I can't locate a package containing the `scala-swing.jar` file anywhere in the Ubuntu repositories. What I tried:

```
sudo apt update 
apt search scala-swing
apt search scala | grep -i swing

apt-file update 
apt-file search scala-swing.jar
apt-file search scala | grep -i swing
```

I got both the `scala` and `scala-library` packages duly installed, but none of them contains `scala-swing.jar` :(

```
# dpkg -L scala        
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/scala
/usr/share/java
/usr/share/java/scalap-2.11.6.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-compiler-2.11.6.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo
/usr/share/maven-repo/org
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.x
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.x/scala-compiler-2.11.x.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.6
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.6/scala-compiler-2.11.6.pom
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/scala
/usr/share/doc/scala/copyright
/usr/share/scala-2.11
/usr/share/scala-2.11/bin
/usr/share/scala-2.11/bin/scalap
/usr/share/scala-2.11/bin/scalac
/usr/share/scala-2.11/bin/scaladoc
/usr/share/scala-2.11/bin/scala
/usr/share/scala-2.11/bin/fsc
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib
/usr/share/scala-2.11/man
/usr/share/scala-2.11/man/man1
/usr/share/scala-2.11/man/man1/scalac.1.gz
/usr/share/scala-2.11/man/man1/scalap.1.gz
/usr/share/scala-2.11/man/man1/scaladoc.1.gz
/usr/share/scala-2.11/man/man1/fsc.1.gz
/usr/share/scala-2.11/man/man1/scala.1.gz
/usr/share/java/scala-compiler-2.11.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-compiler.jar
/usr/share/java/scalap.jar
/usr/share/java/scalap-2.11.jar
/usr/share/scala
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.x/scala-compiler-2.11.x.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.6/scala-compiler-2.11.6.jar
/usr/share/doc/scala/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-library.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/jline.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-xml.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-actors.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-compiler.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/jansi.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-parser-combinators.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scala-reflect.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/scalap.jar
/usr/share/scala-2.11/lib/hawtjni-runtime.jar


# dpkg -L scala-library                                                                       
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/java
/usr/share/java/scala-library-2.11.6.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-actors-2.11.6.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-reflect-2.11.6.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo
/usr/share/maven-repo/org
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.x
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.x/scala-reflect-2.11.x.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.6
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.6/scala-reflect-2.11.6.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-actors
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-actors/2.11.x
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-actors/2.11.x/scala-actors-2.11.x.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-actors/2.11.6
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-actors/2.11.6/scala-actors-2.11.6.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-library
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.x
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.x/scala-library-2.11.x.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.6
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.6/scala-library-2.11.6.pom
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/scala-library
/usr/share/doc/scala-library/copyright
/usr/share/doc/scala-library/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/java/scala-reflect-2.11.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-library-2.11.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-actors.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-actors-2.11.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-reflect.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.x/scala-reflect-2.11.x.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.6/scala-reflect-2.11.6.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-actors/2.11.x/scala-actors-2.11.x.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-actors/2.11.6/scala-actors-2.11.6.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.x/scala-library-2.11.x.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.6/scala-library-2.11.6.jar
```

And here are my sources :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$)" 
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial main restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial universe
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial multiverse
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-security main restricted
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-security universe
deb http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-security multiverse
```

Apparently, back [in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the file WAS present](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/scala-library/filelist) in the scala-library` package, but [no longer in the 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/scala-library/filelist) :( What is the right way to install this file?

Comment: Have you Nfound your answer? If yes, try accepting or providing your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No package in Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) provides `scala-swing.jar` file. However, if you really want you can download the jar file from [java2s site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/scala-swing.htm).